# How to get a value from Database MySQL without Events in my Form Vb Net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

i have a problem to get value `idsiswa` from my database without any events on my form, 
It is my Code :

```
GetIdNilai = {DRnilai.Item("idsiswa")}

StrSQL = "SELECT * from nilai WHERE idsiswa = '" & GetIdNilai.ToString & "' and kodepelajaran = '" & KODEPEL & "' AND semester='" & cSEMESTER & "' AND tahun = '" & THNPEL & "' AND kodeulangan='" & KODEUL & "' order by idsiswa "

CMDSiswa.CommandText = StrSQL
DRsiswa = CMDSiswa.ExecuteReader()
DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()

While DRsiswa.Read
NOMOR = NOMOR + 1
DATA = {NOMOR.ToString, DRsiswa.Item("idsiswa"), DRsiswa.Item("nama"), 0, cSEMESTER, THNPEL}
DataGridView1.Rows.Add(DATA)
End While
```

It's not working, thanks before

Comment: This will be crazy-vulnerable to sql injection attacks. It's practically begging to get hacked.

Comment: mr @JoelCoehoorn do you have any solutions for me sir?

Answer (score 0):

This will be much simpler if you just bind to the datasource. Also, never ever **EVER** use string concatenation like that to build your queries. This code below demonstrates how to handle both issues:

```vb
GetIdNilai = {DRnilai.Item("idsiswa")}

StrSQL = _ 
  "SELECT idsiswa, nama, 0, @Semester, @THNPEL" &
  "FROM nilai " &
  "WHERE idsiswa = @IDNilai AND kodepelajaran = @KODEPEL " &
     " AND semester = @Semester AND tahun = @THNPEL AND kodeulangan = @KODEUL " &
   "ORDER BY idsiswa"

CMDSiswa.CommandText = StrSQL  
'I'm guessing at parameter types here. Use the actual column types and lengths from your database 
CMDSiswa.Parameters.Add("@IDNilai", MySqlDbtype.Int32).Value = CInt(GetIdNilai)
CMDSiswa.Parameters.Add("@KODEPEL", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = KODEPEL
CMDSiswa.Parameters.Add("@Semester", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 1).Value = cSEMESTER
CMDSiswa.Parameters.Add("@THNPEL", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = THNPEL
CMDSiswa.Parameters.Add("@KODEUL", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 2).Value = KODEUL

DRsiswa = CMDSiswa.ExecuteReader()
DataGridView1.DataSource = DRsiswa
```

Comment: thank you sir, i'll try it, but i must add like this variable dim GetIdNilai as String ?

Comment: It looks like you actually want an integer there.